# Javascript-Create HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hello how would I create this in Javascript?:

```
  You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}</span></strong> characters left.<br/>
```

add it above this:

```
 function editCommentToggle( id )
{
    theRow = document.getElementById("id"+id);
    //user = theRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    //date = theRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    com = theRow.cells[2].innerText ;


    idx = 2;
    maxlength = 250;

                // Comment field
        cell = theRow.cells[idx];
        while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 ) cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);

        //spanTag = document.createElement("span"); 
        //spanTag.innerHTML = "id='commentsCounter'>" + maxlength + "</span>characters left.<br/>" 
        //cell.appendChild(spanTag);
        element = document.createElement("textarea");
        element.id="comments-"+id;
        element.rows="3";
        element.value = com;
        element.style.width = "400px";
        element.maxLength = "250";
        element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit(undefined, maxlength, this);}; 
        cell.appendChild(element);

        $(function()
                {
                    setTimeout("syncCommentTableSizes()",0);    <%-- Run after HTC code --%>
                });

    // Actions field
    cell = theRow.cells[++idx];
    while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 ) cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);

    link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = 'javascript:saveComment('+id+')';

    element = document.createElement( "img" );
    element.className = "edit"; // check if we need this changed
    element.src="../images/icon_save.gif";
    element.border="0";
    element.alt = "Save";

    link.appendChild( element );

    cell.appendChild(link);
    cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode("  ") );

    link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = 'javascript:cancelCommentEdit('+id+')';

    element = document.createElement( "img" );
    element.className = "delete"; // check if we need this changed
    element.src="../images/icon_cancel.gif";
    element.border="0";
    element.alt = "Cancel";

    link.appendChild(element);
    cell.appendChild(link);
}
```

jsp:

```
<table id="add-comment-table" class="data_table" style="border-top-style: none; margin-top: 0px;">
<td colspan="3">
    You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}</span></strong> characters left.<br/>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="3"
        onfocus="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
        onkeydown="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
        onkeyup="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"></textarea>
        <a href="javascript:addComment();"><img src="../images/icon_add.gif" border="0" alt="Add"/></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Enclose it in single quotes, and use backslashes to escape the ones around COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH?

Comment: Could you offer more by way of explanation?

Comment: I actually dont need `${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}`...the const in the # 250.  I need to build this html in javascript.  and put it above this I already built:

Comment: Edit your post, rather than putting it all in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output your constant inside the hidden div.

You can then grab the innerHTML from the html, rather than trying to set it via javascript.

```
<div id="maxSize" style="display:none;">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}</div>
<span id="commentsCounter"></span>
<div onclick="update()">Click</div>

<script>
    function update()
    {
        var maxLength = parseInt( document.getElementById( "maxSize" ).innerHTML );
        document.getElementById( "commentsCounter" ).innerHTML = maxLength;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put this html to an element for example

```
elem.innerHTML = "your html generated code";
```

of course using single quote for your html

Comment: so like this:  `elem.innerHTML = "You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}</span></strong> characters left.<br/>"`  ???

Comment: When you have found the right answer, make sure to mark it as that.